# Regex matching between # delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, exactly as shown and im trying to match the content which is between the delimiters.

```
# a
This is what should be matched/returned
# \a
```

The `# a` and the `# \a` are the delimiters.

PHP/Regex that's not matching:

```
$str = <<<EOD

# a
this is what should be returned
# \a

EOD;

preg_match("/#\sa\n(.*)\n#\s\\a/m", $str, $matches);

/*
Array
(
)
*/
print_r($matches);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's with the `{1}`? You can just delete them, the regex is the same without them.

Comment: Probably need to use single quotes or double escape your backslash. Also `{1}` not not needed as the character itself represents one.

Comment: Have you tried adding the multiline modifier? `"/#{1}\s{1}a{1}\n{1}(.*)\n#{1}\s{1}\\a{1}/m"`

Comment: The {1} is redundant, as it means matches exactly one time.  Anyways, are you missing the multiline flag for a php regex?

Comment: Don't forget to downvote it's such a bad question. ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several ways to do it:

1. `s` modifier for `.` to match newlines
2. `\\\\` to escape the `\`
3. There is probably a `\r\n` instead of just a `\n` so I used `\s`

---

```
 preg_match("/#\sa\s(.*)\s#\s\\\\a/s", $str, $matches);
```

Why in the world do you use `{1}` everywhere?

Comment: Thanks, thats it. so it was the `\n` and double escaping the backslash. Im not great at regex :s

Comment: And `s` modifier. `.` char won't match newlines without it. So you might not need the second `\s`.  Or you could get rid of the `s` and use `\s+` but then add `?` to `.*`.  Several ways.

Comment: Also, probably want to make the `.*` non-greedy. `.*?`